Python SANE scanner (Canon lide 400) errors: invalid argument
I'm trying to access my canon Lide 400 scanner using python.
My setup: WSL ubuntu (i've attached the usb port, lsub shows the canon scanner)
The code i'm currently using:
import snoop
import stackprinter
stackprinter.set_excepthook(style='darkbg2') 
from loguru import logger
logger.add("logfile.log", rotation="500 MB",mode = "w")    # Automatically rotate too big file

import time
import sane
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


def init_scanner():
    """Initialize SANE and find available devices."""
    sane.init()
    devices = sane.get_devices()
    print("Available devices:")
    for device in devices:
        print(f"- {device[0]} ({device[1]} {device[2]})")
    return devices

def find_canon_scanner(prefer_escl=True):
    """
    Find the Canon LIDE 400 scanner device name.
    
    Args:
        prefer_escl (bool): If True, prefer the ESCL device over AirScan
    """
    devices = init_scanner()
    escl_device = None
    airscan_device = None
    
    for device in devices:
        if 'lide 400' in device[2].lower():
            if 'escl:' in device[0].lower():
                escl_device = device[0]
            elif 'airscan:' in device[0].lower():
                airscan_device = device[0]
    
    # Return the preferred device or fallback to the available one
    if prefer_escl:
        return escl_device or airscan_device
    return airscan_device or escl_device

def scan_image(dpi=300, mode='color', format='png', prefer_escl=True):
    """
    Scan an image using the Canon LIDE 400.
    
    Args:
        dpi (int): Scanning resolution in DPI
        mode (str): Scanning mode ('color', 'gray', or 'lineart')
        format (str): Output format ('png', 'jpeg', etc.)
        prefer_escl (bool): If True, prefer the ESCL device over AirScan
    
    Returns:
        str: Path to saved image file
    """
    try:
        # Find the scanner
        device_name = find_canon_scanner(prefer_escl)
        if not device_name:
            raise Exception("Canon LIDE 400 scanner not found")
            
        print(f"Using scanner: {device_name}")
        
        # Open the device
        scanner = sane.open(device_name)
        
        # Configure scanner settings
        scanner.mode = mode
        scanner.resolution = dpi
        
        # Some scanners need a moment to initialize
        time.sleep(1)
        
        # Start the scan
        print("Starting scan...")
        scanner.start()
        
        # Get the image
        img = scanner.snap()
        
        # Convert to PIL Image
        if mode == 'color':
            pil_img = Image.fromarray(img)
        else:
            pil_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img))
        
        # Save the image
        timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        output_file = f'scan_{timestamp}_{mode}_{dpi}dpi.{format}'
        pil_img.save(output_file, format=format)
        print(f"Scan saved as {output_file}")
        
        # Clean up
        scanner.close()
        
        return output_file
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during scanning: {str(e)}")
        if 'scanner' in locals():
            scanner.close()
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scan_image(
        dpi=300,
        mode='color',
        format='png',
        prefer_escl=True
    )

Available devices:

escl:http://10.255.255.254:60000 (Canon LiDE 400 (USB))
airscan:e0:Canon LiDE 400 (USB) (eSCL Canon LiDE 400 (USB))

The error:
Error getting scanner options: Invalid argument

Please post the full stack trace for the error
